# Problem of encoding characters (apostrophes) in my posts publications

Tags: plugins, posts, database

I currently have a big apostrophes problem when my articles are published on my website, because for an example of a word like "l'associé", my article is published with characters that replace the apostrophe like on the image 
in attachment.

I specify that I use an automatic publishing plugin (using rss feeds) and oddly, when I post (manually) an article and that I add quotes there is no problem.

I checked the encoding of my database that was in utf8mb4 general but that I changed to utf8 general to see if I could solve my problem, but nothing changed, I also checked with notepad ++ if there was not one 
by checking that my file wp-config.php was not encoded in utf8 with bom, which usually creates accent problems in French.

So I suspect it could come from either the wordpress theme (Sahifa) or the plugin (wp-automatic) that publishes my articles from rss feeds.

Do you have a track that can guide me on the origin of the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually happens to me. I usually resolve this via string replace function.
First one replaces the WordPress **Content** area. The second filter is replacing the **Title** area.

Check out the **str_replace** array and insert your `&#339;` to your own string before the **$content** array.

```
function replace_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() )
    // Add image to the beginning of each page
    $content = str_replace(array('&laquo;','&quot;', '&#8220;', '&#8221;'), '"', $content);

    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_the_content_filter', 20 );

function replace_the_title_filter( $content ) {

    // Add image to the beginning of each page
    $content = str_replace(array('&laquo;','&quot;', '&#8220;', '&#8221;'), '"', $content);

    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'replace_the_title_filter', 20 );
```

I hope that helps. Please be careful on the **Title** or Content section. If you wanna do it on Attachment title then check the https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_caption/.

Goodluck.

Comment: Main reason for this issue is from Translations. If you had translation file in your WP and then main language has Translations issue. If you resolve main Translation then it will not come up.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler still:

```
 function RemoveTheSlashes( $content ) 
    {
    $FixedContent = stripslashes($content);

     // Returns the content.
     return $FixedContent ;
   }
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'RemoveTheSlashes', 20 );
```

Will turn this:  /' into just the '